# Representing tree/graph structures for deep learning

Tags: data-transformation, deep-learning, graph-theory

Let's say I'm analysing an object that can have an unknown number of nested sub objects which a variable number of properties. Basically, a graph structure akin to HTML or XML where you can have nested objects, which can all have the same set of sparse non binary properties, where objects with identical properties can repeat in different parts of the graph, and the graph doesn't have a directly limited size or depth.

Is there any reasonable way to generally represent this for a deep learning algorithm?

I've thought about only considering the top level graph node and doing a walk through the graph to analyze each node in it one by one, but this robs me of a lot of potentially useful contextual info and creates difficulties in creating a graph like this from base data if the network can only handle the "top level" node, but the data comes as a flat object like an image or sound.

Any suggestions on how to represent an arbitrary graph structure with a limited but possibly very large set of properties for each node and each node possibly repeating in multiple places in the graph and having an unknown number of children?

Can't wrap my mind around any way to reconcile this kind of data with deep learning.